# NullPointerException on drawer_layout Android Template

Tags: java, android, null

so I'm trying to switch Fragments on my app with the Navigation Drawer template in Android Studio 1.0.2.

It is giving me a null pointer exception on mNavigationDrawer.setup, and it is the drawer_layout that is null.

Here is activity_main.xml where drawer_layout is

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.example.intokyle.template.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/weekly_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:name="com.example.intokyle.template.weeklyFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/abc_list_menu_item_icon" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/daily_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:name="com.example.intokyle.template.dailyFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/abc_list_menu_item_icon" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the onCreate method in MainActivity,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_weekly);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp( //here is where the error is
        R.id.navigation_drawer,
        (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

}
```

This is what the debugger gives me

```
> 04-07 08:05:19.217    1145-1145/com.example.intokyle.template E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.intokyle.template, PID: 1145
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.intokyle.template/com.example.intokyle.template.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.intokyle.template.NavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(int, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.intokyle.template.NavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(int, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.intokyle.template.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try to check in fragments is extended from v4 support fragment and you extend your activity with ActionBarActivity if supporting app below api 16

Comment: Thanks for the response. ActionBarActivity is extended at the top of the class, and im using android.support.v4.app.Fragment, im not sure what you mean by check in fragments is extended from v4 support fragment, and im not supporting anything under 16.